# Removing Duplicate Rows Based on Three Columns

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, rows

In the data frame, you can see that the two columns (Sample and SampleDate) are where the duplicates are observed; meaning, if the row values in those two columns are identical, then it is a duplicated row. For each duplicate record, I am trying to remove only one of the duplicate rows. However, the twist to this is that I want to keep the row where the WQStandard column is not blank. The data frame is over 6,000 rows long and has many different types of names in the Parameter column.

```
structure(list(Parameter = c("1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", 
"1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,1-Trichloroethane", "1,1,2,2-Tetrachloroethane", 
"1,1,2,2-Tetrachloroethane", "1,1,2,2-Tetrachloroethane", "1,1,2,2-Tetrachloroethane", 
"1,1,2,2-Tetrachloroethane", "1,1,2,2-Tetrachloroethane", "1,1,2,2-Tetrachloroethane"
), Unit = c("mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", 
"mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", 
"mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", 
"mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", 
"mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", 
"mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", 
"mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L"), WaterQualityStandardId = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA), Parameter_Id = c(37, 
37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 
144, 144), WaterQualityStandard = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "ABTier1CommIndCoarse-2019", NA, "ABTier1CommIndCoarse-2019", 
NA, "ABTier1CommIndCoarse-2019", NA), Sample_Id = c(134762, 134763, 
134781, 134782, 134800, 134801, 134819, 134820, 134826, 134843, 
134844, 134862, 134863, 134878, 134879, 134932, 134933, 134984, 
134985, 135038, 135039, 135092, 135093, 135139, 135140, 135184, 
135185, 135230, 135231, 135277, 135278, 135323, 135324, 135369, 
135370, 135414, 135415, 135454, 135455, 135498, 135499, 135537, 
135538, 134762, 134762, 134763, 134763, 134781, 134781, 134782
), ExceedanceColor = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, -886475, NA, -886475, NA, -886475, NA), Value = c(5e-04, 
5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 
5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 
5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 
5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 
5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 
5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04), StandardLowerLimit = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5e-04, 0, 5e-04, 0, 5e-04, 0, 
5e-04), QCFlag = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), StandardUpperLimit = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 
0.004, 0.004), Qualifier = c("<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", 
"<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", 
"<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", 
"<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", "<", 
"<", "<", "<", "<"), EffectiveLowerLimit = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5e-04, 0, 5e-04, 0, 5e-04, 0, 5e-04
), Sample = c("BF11-10A43987", "BF11-10A44125", "BF11-10B43987", 
"BF11-10B44125", "BF11-11A43987", "BF11-11A44125", "BF11-11B43987", 
"BF11-11B44125", "BF11-11C43987", "BF11-1243992", "BF11-1244125", 
"BF11-13A43992", "BF11-13A44125", "BF11-13B43992", "BF11-13B44125", 
"BF92-0143992", "BF92-0144126", "BF92-0243992", "BF92-0244126", 
"BF92-0343992", "BF92-0344126", "BF92-0443992", "BF92-0444126", 
"BF97-01D43992", "BF97-01D44121", "BF97-01S43992", "BF97-01S44121", 
"BF97-02D43992", "BF97-02D44121", "BF97-02S43992", "BF97-02S44121", 
"BF97-03D43992", "BF97-03D44121", "BF97-03S43992", "BF97-03S44121", 
"BF97-04D43987", "BF97-04D44125", "BF97-04S43987", "BF97-04S44125", 
"BF97-05D43987", "BF97-05D44125", "BF97-05S43987", "BF97-05S44125", 
"BF11-10A43987", "BF11-10A43987", "BF11-10A44125", "BF11-10A44125", 
"BF11-10B43987", "BF11-10B43987", "BF11-10B44125"), EffectiveUpperLimit = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 
0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004), SampleDate = structure(c(1591315200, 
1603152000, 1591315200, 1603152000, 1591315200, 1603152000, 1591315200, 
1603152000, 1591315200, 1591660800, 1603152000, 1591660800, 1603152000, 
1591660800, 1603152000, 1591660800, 1603238400, 1591660800, 1603238400, 
1591660800, 1603238400, 1591660800, 1603238400, 1591660800, 1602806400, 
1591660800, 1602806400, 1591660800, 1602806400, 1591660800, 1602806400, 
1591660800, 1602806400, 1591660800, 1602806400, 1591315200, 1603152000, 
1591315200, 1603152000, 1591315200, 1603152000, 1591315200, 1603152000, 
1591315200, 1591315200, 1603152000, 1603152000, 1591315200, 1591315200, 
1603152000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    StandardUnit = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", 
    "mg/L"), Station = c(22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 25, 25, 26, 
    27, 27, 28, 28, 29, 29, 30, 30, 31, 31, 32, 32, 33, 33, 34, 
    34, 35, 35, 36, 36, 37, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 40, 40, 41, 41, 
    42, 42, 43, 43, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23), StandardActive = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, 
    NA, TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA), isExceedance = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), QualifierValue = c("<0.0005", "<0.0005", 
    "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", 
    "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", 
    "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", 
    "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", 
    "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", 
    "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", 
    "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", 
    "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005", "<0.0005"
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

Comment: Please share CODE, NOT IMAGES of your data. You can use `dput()`

Comment: sorry I am such a newbie at this. I'm not sure how to use dput() but I will gladly do so

Comment: Just call `dput(Anndata)`. Copy/paste the output from the console into the question

Answer (score 0):

This was kind of tricky and I am sure there is a more efficient way to do this, but I think this code satisfies what you're looking for. Let me know if the output doesn't look right to you.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)

# df <- "your data"

# make a variable (called x) that represents a unique combination of Sample and SampleDate 
# this is what defines the duplicate values
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(x = paste0(Sample, as.numeric(SampleDate))) %>%
  mutate(x = as.factor(x))

df2 <- plyr::ddply(df2, "x", transform, y = seq(from = 0, by = 1, length.out = length(x)))

df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(z = if_else(y == 0, 0, 1))

# remove if both y and z are 1
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!(y == 1 & z == 1))
```